# LinkedIn Login button is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access linkedIn from my website. For that I have created a new Application and get the API key. And implemented in my code below. This gives me the blank page but works only in Javascript API developer console.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
     api_key: mykey
      authorize: true
             </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="In/Login">
    Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>
    </script>
    </body>
```

Please help to get the login button..

Answer (score 1):

The code looks alright as far as I can tell. As mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api):

- Verify that your API key, is specified in the framework script tag.
- Verify that the full domain name you are using to access the html
  file is specified in the key's configuration details.
- Check your JavaScript Console for any framework errors.
- If you are using Firebug or WebKit's Developer Tools, check to make
  sure that the following files were loaded automatically: in.js,
  userspace.js and framework.js

Comment: hmm..am new to javascript..I have just given my company url in domain name..is that wrong?

Comment: Are you trying it on a local host or an actual domain? You have to  specify the complete fully-qualified domain as `we don't do subdomain wildcards or substring matching. For example, http://www.example.com is okay, but *.example.com is not`

Comment: hmm am trying it in localhost only.

Comment: Then mention that as the domain name. Wherever you're running it right now **not** your company url.

Comment: okay fine..now i have given this http://localhost.. again it showing the blank page..are sure the problem is in domain name?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you need a specific jQuery version to make the button appear!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>
```

And to show the Button you will need also this somewhere BUT INSIDE A BODY TAG!!!

```
<body>
<script type="IN/Login"></script>
</body>
```

hope that will give some light to the issue!